# Difference between "Are you sure to continue?" and "Are you sure you want to continue?"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, interrogatives

> **A**: "Are you sure to continue?"
>   **B**: "Are you sure you want to continue?"

Is the first sentence grammatically correct? And what is the difference? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are you sure to continue?

This is asking if it's a *given* that you will continue. A possible response is, "Yes, it's certain I will continue (to do this)."

> Are you sure you want to continue?

This is asking you it's your *desire* to continue, regardless of whether you actually will or won't. A possible response is, "Yes, I'm sure I want to."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to solidify the concept: Suppose there is a disclaimer about age restricted content in a web page. After the disclaimer which one is  a more apt question to ask?

Comment: @ArJ In your scenario, the second question by far the more likely.